# Is it possible to disable a Parameterized test basis arguments in Junit5

Tags: java, junit5, junit5-extension-model

I have a scenario where I'm trying to disable parameterized tests but I don't  want to disable all of them. Consider the below mock scenario

```
@CsvSource({
      "1,1",
      "2,2",
      "3,not3"
  })
  @ExtendWith(DisableParameterized.class)
  @ParameterizedTest( name = "Test for {0} is equal to {1}")
  void equality(String expected, String actual) {
    assertEquals(expected, actual, "Not as expected");
  }
```

Is it possible to write a `DisableParameterized implements ExecutionCondition` which can disable one of the Parameterized tests basis some meta data.

The only proper info I can make out about ParameterizedTests in the

```
public ConditionEvaluationResult evaluateExecutionCondition(ExtensionContext extensionContext)
```

is the `displayName`
Is there some other way to generically provide some sort of meta data to disable the Parameterized tests ?

if I mark them as @Disabled, it disables all of the ParameterizedTests to the point that it doesn't even invoke the individual tests and stops at the method level.

Edit : 
As mentioned by Sam below, it's not possible to do it using standard API till the issues mentioned are fixed/implemented and release in a newer version.
I was however able to write a code using reflection to achieve what I wanted, so I've added an answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, till the actual API is implemented under the issues Sam has mentioned, the only way to extract arguments is as below. i.e. using reflection
Which is a dirty way for most people, but that's the only way

Then after extracting the arguments, we can manipulate them however we want.

```
@Override
  public ConditionEvaluationResult evaluateExecutionCondition(ExtensionContext context) {
    return disableRequiredOnParameterizedTests(context);
  }

private ConditionEvaluationResult disableRequiredOnParameterizedTests(ExtensionContext context) {
    // See if my custom annotation is present on the test
    var onParameters = findRepeatableAnnotation(context, DisableOnParameter.class);
    // Or if the test is a Parameterized test after all
    // We have access to arguments when the test will be at method level, i.e. MethodExtensionContext
    if (!MethodExtensionContext.class.isAssignableFrom(context.getClass())
        || findAnnotations(context, ParameterizedTest.class).isEmpty()
        || onParameters.isEmpty()) {
      return enabled("Not set to disable");
    }
    List<Object> arguments = getArguments(context);
    boolean enable = true;
    // Do what you want with arguments
    .
    .
    .
    return enable ? enabled("Enabling") ? disabled("Disabling");
  }

/**
   * A blanket exception safe function to extract arguments from Extension context using
   * reflection since we don't have direct access to the API
   * https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1139
   *
   * @param context needs to be of {@link MethodExtensionContext} type since only at that stage
   *     arguments can be extracted
   * @return List of argument objects, empty if any error occurs
   */
  private static List<Object> getArguments(ExtensionContext context) {
    try {
      if(MethodExtensionContext.class.isAssignableFrom(context.getClass())) {
        return emptyList();
      }
      Method method = findMethod(context.getClass(), "getTestDescriptor").orElseThrow();
      TestMethodTestDescriptor descriptor =
          (TestMethodTestDescriptor) invokeMethod(method, context);

      // Get the TestTemplateInvocationContext
      Field templateField = descriptor.getClass().getDeclaredField("invocationContext");
      templateField.setAccessible(true);
      TestTemplateInvocationContext template =
          (TestTemplateInvocationContext) templateField.get(descriptor);

      // Get the params finally
      Field argumentsField = template.getClass().getDeclaredField("arguments");
      argumentsField.setAccessible(true);
      return asList((Object[]) argumentsField.get(template));
    } catch (Throwable ignored) {
      return emptyList();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

No, as of JUnit Jupiter 5.6 (pending GA release at the time of this writing), there is no way to access the arguments used to invoked a parameterized test.

For the time being, the only way to infer that type of information is indeed via the display name.

The following open JUnit 5 issues are related to this topic.

- https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1139
- https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1668
- https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1884

Comment: Thanks Sam, I found these issues after I had posted my query, unfortunately I had to come up with a way to get to the arguments data using reflection. I can see that someone recently posted a similar solution on one of these issues.
I'm eagerly waiting to replace the reflections with an actual API when you finally release it.